# Aumentar dias automáticamente en bbdd

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una aplicación donde cada usuario puede solicitar sus vaccaciones. Hay dos tipos de usuarios, `fijos` y `temporales`. Los usuarios fijos tienen 24 dias al año para las vacaciones. La duda viene con los usuarios temporales.

A los usuarios temporales se les suma `2 dias` por mes trabajado hasta el 31 de diciembre de ese año. Por ejemplo:

`usuario1` entró a la empresa el `25/01/2019`, hasta el `31/12/2019` tendría que aumentarle 2 días por mes trabajado hasta llegar a esa fecha, en total 22 dias. A partir del `01/01/2020`, esos 2 días, se le van aumentando cada mes natural y empezaría desde 0, osea que el `01/01/2020` tendría 0 días y el `01/02/2020` tendría 2 dias.

¿Hay alguna función `PHP` o en `MySQL` un procedimiento para que esos 2 días los añada automaticamente a la base de datos?

En la base de datos tengo una tabla `usuario` que tiene los siguientes campos:

```
nombre    dias_disponibles
=======   =================
usuario1           0
```

A esos `dias_disponibles` es a los que hay que aumentar los días

Comment: ¿Usas cPanel en el servidor? Si es así, puedes usar los Cron Job (Trabajos automáticos) para hacerlo. Si es así, dímelo y te publico una respuesta con todos los detalles.

Comment: @BrahimKhallota ahora mismo uso el phpmyadmin